Normal Modes in the Debye Model
In the Debye model I understand that our system of atoms can vibrate collectively at certain normal modes. Here, each normal mode of vibration is sort of like a quantum harmonic oscillator and therefore it has many energy eigenstates associated with it. We know how to do our statistical mechanics on these quantum harmonic oscillators so we find an average energy for each normal mode. Up to now all is good but the final step alludes me.
Now to find the total energy we sum over all the normal modes (k) in the form of an integral, making sure we respect the $\Delta k$ and $k_{max}$ of our system. My question is, why are we treating every normal mode as equals?
When we classically think about normal modes, they sort of form a basis of how our system can vibrate and depending on our initial conditions we take a linear combination of our normal modes. Therefore, clearly certain normal modes are more favoured than others depending on our initial conditions. However, we are dealing with statistical mechancis where our systems are not aware of their initial conditions and we consider every possible microstate of the system so the sentence before is not valid. However, even in statistical mechanics every state also has a boltzmann factored probability associated with it so all the microstates are not on equal footing. Therefore, why do we just some over all the normal modes as if all of them are equally relevant for our system?

Regarding the initial conditions, as you say, in statistical mechanics they are irrelevant because the system is assumed to be in thermal equilibrium. If you want, you can imagine that the thermal fluctuations are constantly resetting the initial conditions so that effectively all of them play the same role. More precisely, it can be shown that the probability distribution that maximizes the entropy of a system is the uniform one, so unless you have some macroscopic information of the system, one has to treat all states with an equal weight.
Regarding the Boltzmann factor, you indeed must weight every microstate depending on its energy. More precisely, given a Hamiltonian $H=n\hbar \omega$, the partition function is:
$$
Z = \prod_\omega \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\beta \hbar \omega n}
$$
We have factored $Z$ because we are consider that different frequencies do not interact with one another. Now, using the geomertic series formula and taking the logarithm, this reduces to:
$$
\log Z = -\sum_\omega \log(1-e^{-\beta \hbar \omega}) \approx -\int_0^{\omega_D} g(\omega) \log(1-e^{-\beta \hbar \omega })
$$
We have used the continuum limit by substituting the sum by an integral with the corresponding density of states. The upper limit of integration is the Debye frequency, i.e., the maximum frequency allowed by the spacing in the underlying lattice.
Finally, we use that $U=-\partial_\beta \log Z$ and integrate by parts, obtaining:
$$
U = \int_0^{\omega_D} d\omega g(\omega)  \frac{\hbar \omega}{e^{\beta \hbar \omega}-1}
$$
So, summing up, the Bose-Einstein distribution that appears in the formula of the internal energy is taking into account that different states are weighted differently, following the Boltzmann factor but also taking into account the fact that phonons are bosons, and thus follow quantum statistics.

Strictly speaking, the Debye frequency is not the maximum frequency for the actual lattice.  For a latter with $N$ atoms, $\omega_{D}=(6\pi^{2}N/V)^{1/3}v_{s}$ is the $3N$-th normal mode frequency of a linear continuum.  The model gives the right behavior at low and high temperatures (in terms of $kT$ versus $\hbar\omega_{D}$), but not generally in the intermediate range, where getting accurate expressions requires having a more accurate understanding of the density of states.

Thank you! Starting out with the partition function like that made things very clear, and I feel like this type of explanation is missing from conventional material.
